# Node JS Date Object behaves strangely around daylight savings time

Tags: javascript, node.js, dst

So I am working on a rather larger project and I ran into a bug and I wanted to see what I could be doing wrong. I loop though a large amount of data and round off some dates to clean my output into 15 minute buckets.

CODE:

```js
//how I've been doing things
let expectedBehvaior = new Date("2020-11-01T05:14:00.000Z");
console.log(expectedBehvaior.toISOString());
expectedBehvaior.setMinutes(0);
console.log(expectedBehvaior.toISOString());

//using set minutes creates an issue for only hours 6 UTC on Nov 1st 2020
let crazyDate = new Date("2020-11-01T06:14:00.000Z");
console.log(crazyDate.toISOString());
crazyDate.setMinutes(0);
console.log(crazyDate.toISOString());

//how i fixed it
let fixedDate = new Date("2020-11-01T06:14:00.000Z");
console.log(fixedDate.toISOString());
fixedDate.setTime(fixedDate.getTime() - 60000 * fixedDate.getMinutes());
console.log(fixedDate.toISOString());
```

OUTPUT:

```
2020-11-01T05:14:00.000Z
2020-11-01T05:00:00.000Z
2020-11-01T06:14:00.000Z
2020-11-01T05:00:00.000Z
2020-11-01T06:14:00.000Z
2020-11-01T06:00:00.000Z
```

This seems related to daylight savings time in the US as the same thing happens on November 3rd 2019. Not sure how Date.setMinutes works in the background and was hoping someone could explain the behavior.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I am expecting the hour to remain the same after I call crazyDate.setMinutes(0). Instead it sets it back to 0500 UTC as opposed to 0600 UTC.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly it is that you didn't expect about how the code works?

Comment: Also in the US November is never in Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: On Safari, I think I get the expected results. The first group rounds to 05:00:00, the second group rounds to 06:00:00 and the final group rounds to 6:00:00.

Comment: When I run the snippet where I am (Central Standard Time, US) I get hours 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6

Comment: I added an edit to the question to clarify the expected behavior.

Comment: This error happens when DST ends. I go the same result using November 3rd 2019.

Comment: I have not tried other browsers but my main concern is Nodejs as that is what I am using.

Comment: I'm on New York (eastern Standard Time) so that may be part of the issue.